# Sticky element does not start at edge of screen

Tags: html, sticky

My sticky element does not start at the edge of the screen and it is very annoying:

```
div.sticky {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 500;
  html, body {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could provide your code as Code Snippet that also includes your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is most likely coming from the margin that is applied to the body by default, just make sure to set it to `0`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

div.sticky {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky"></div>
```